# Rails 4 Model, switch DB depending on scenario - Seeking Optimal Design Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, amazon-redshift

I have a platform where a large amount of data (millions of records per day) will be stored in Amazon Redshift, but that data will also be regularly processed by a cronjob, and aggregated statistics will then be created in the PostgreSQL db that runs my Rails app, while old data will be purged from Redshift.

Essentially, this means that for statistics on recent events (in the last day or two), my Rails model will need to pull from Redshift, but otherwise, it will need to pull from PostgreSQL. Since the PostgreSQL db will only contain aggregated statistics, the queries will also be different.

It's not difficult to code this, but I'm not sure how such a model fits in with Rails. ActiveRecord seems to couple the model pretty tightly to a db implementation, so I'm thinking that I need to create a primary model that does not extend ActiveRecords, plus an ActiveRecord model and a lib class to handle the Redshift queries. Is this the optimal design for my scenario, or are there other design patterns I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the Redshift tables from Postgres using a Foreign Data Wrapper. See here for setup guide: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/foreign-data-wrappers-for-postgresql

Comment: How does this integrate with ActiveRecord?
In this scenario where would the logic go to determine whether to use the Redshift version of the model or the Postgres version? How does it account for the fact that the queries will be different for the two DB's?

Comment: You'd have to add logic to you application that knows when to use which DB. Alternatively you could wrap both the Postgres table and the Redshift table in a UNION ALL view and treat them as a single model. FWIW, I would actually suggest just putting all of this data in Redshift.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the question. I'm not asking TECHNICALLY how to do this, I know how to do this.
What I am trying to get at is what DESIGN PATTERN to use. 
I am thinking this needs a factory object that produces the correct version of the model. I am trying to decide if this is the best pattern, and where the best place to put such code in a Rails app would be--it's app specific so it doesn't belong in /lib.